# Delphi - Mapping function unexpected output

Tags: python, delphi, floating-point, mapping, range

Found this genius [map](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) function in Arduino library.  Wrote the same thing i Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
function map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Integer): extended;
begin
  result := (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
end;
var
  y, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Integer;
  i: integer;
  m: extended;
begin
  in_min := 0;
  in_max := 6406963;
  out_min := 0;
  out_max := 474;
  y := 0;

  for i := in_min to in_max do begin
    m := map(i, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max);
    if round(m) <> y then begin
        y := round(m);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i) + ' = ' + FloatToStr(m));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Got some funny results from it, so I wrote the same thing in Python to check and verify with:

```
def map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    "Re-maps a number from one range to another."
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min

if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_min = 0
    in_max = 6406963
    out_min = 0
    out_max = 474
    y = 0
    for i in range(in_min, in_max):
        m = map(i, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max)
        if round(m) != y:
            y = round(m)
            print(i, ' = ', m)
```

Here is a snippet from my results:

```
DELPI                           EXPECTED (Python)
   6759 =    0,500044404813        6759  =    0.50004440481395
1358439 =  100,500047526418     1358439  =  100.50004752641775
2710119 =  200,500050648022     2710119  =  200.50005064802153
4061799 =  300,500053769625     4061799  =  300.5000537696253
4521370 =  334,500040034569     4521370  =  334.50004003456866
4530557 = -335,179597260043     4534887  =  335.50005486218663
5418335 = -269,499996488196     5413479  =  400.5000568912291
6405062 = -196,499949820219     6400205  =  473.50002957719596
```

So, why does my Delphi code produce negative numbers as output and what should be done to correct this?

Comment: 4530557 * 474 = -2147483278 in 32-bit arithmetic (overflow), hence the minus. Delphi uses 32-bit integers, Python AFAIK arbitrary precision integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of integer parameters leads to overflow, which explains the negative values. This sub-expression:

```
(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)
```

only contains integer operands and so is performed using integer arithmetic. And this can overflow. The first value that produces a negative output is `x = 4530557`. Let's dig a little deeper by working through the calculation:

```
x                                  = 4530557
x - in_min                         = 4530557
out_max - out_min                  = 474
(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) = 2147484018
```

And that value is greater than `high(Integer)` and so overflows to be a negative value.

You should use floating point parameters in the function to avoid this pitfall.

As for the other values, those are the same numbers to the precision that the arithmetic is performed. Your Delphi code performs arithmetic at 64 bit extended precision. The Python code at 53 bit double precision.

In my view it is preferable to avoid 64 bit extended precision. It is non-standard and limited to certain platforms. It is available on 32 bit x86 but 64 bit x64 compilers use the SSE unit for floating point and that unit does not support 64 bit extended precision. And most of all, the alignment of the data type leads to very poor read/write memory performance.

So if you want portability of arithmetic I suggest you stick to 53 bit double precision. Stop using the `Extended` type and use `Double` instead. And configure the floating point unit to operate to 53 bit precision.

So, the net result is this function:

```
function map(const x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Double): Double;
begin
  result := (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Integers are overflowing and you should be using Double.

Change

```
function map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Integer): extended;
```

To

```
function map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Int64): double;
```

Comment: This simply pushes the problem further away, but it remains. Floating point arguments should be used.

Comment: Yes, your answer is better.

Answer (score -1):

Use a **Double** instead of **Extended** and you'll get the same result

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  function map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Integer): Double;
  begin
    result := (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
  end;
var
  y, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  m: Double;
begin
  in_min := 0;
  in_max := 6406963;
  out_min := 0;
  out_max := 474;
  y := 0;

  for i := in_min to in_max do
  begin
    m := map(i, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max);
    if round(m) <> y then
    begin
      y := round(m);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i) + ' = ' + FloatToStr(m));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT:** See david's answer for an explanation;

Comment: This still returns negative values because the Integer is overflowing.

Comment: At which input value?

Comment: `(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)` can overflow a signed 32 bit integer and does in his test.

Comment: Can I make a comment on your answer. You say, *See david's answer for an explanation.* I don't find that very satisfactory. If you aren't prepared to explain an answer, then perhaps it's better not to bother. If you want to be terse then maybe a comment would be better. In my view, if you are prepared to answer, you should be prepared to explain it. It doesn't matter if another answer exists already. If you think you can explain it better, then it doesn't matter if there is some overlap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan don't you have some thing to do.